# Duplicate Error Shows in Validation Summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have an aspx page with multiple nested ascx usercontrols on it. innermost usercontrols shows in bootstrap modal box and their contents is in an update panel.
My problem is in some user controls that I have error summary every error add twice in Page_Validators and show twice in Error Summary.

I try to find out problem , but I don't know why I got this error. My Validation Group is unique , I have only on validation Summary.

**Update**

I found out this only occur for usercontrols with dispay: none panels. Validation on this panels first time that aspx page load , added to Page_Validators and sencond time when My Custom Post Back Event Occur added again to Page_Validators!!! Why This issue occur ? how to solve it?
please help me solve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A reason for such behavior could be duplicate scripts registered. Are you loading all your scripts from one single location? Are you sure there are no duplicate scripts registered in DOM?

For example :

if you have two actions assigned to a click event

```
$("#brandLogo").click(function(){
  alert("hi");
});

$("#brandLogo").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
});
```

Both the alerts will be fired when you click on `$("#brandLogo")`.

Comment: No , Scripts registered only one time.